# XPath for w:p without certain ancestor elements?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, openxml

I have been following an example for using the XPath `not ancestor` selector in the form of `.//x[not(ancestor::w:tbl)]` but it is not behaving as I expect.

I am parsing a Word DOCX file that has a table in it.  I am using the python lxml library to parse it as XML.  I want to get paragraph items that do not have a table element anywhere in their ancestor tree.

I type the following in console:

```
selector = './/w:p[not(ancestor::w:drawing)][not(ancestor::w:tbl)][not(ancestor::v:textbox)][not(ancestor::wps:wsp)][not(ancestor::mc:Fallback)]
nsDict = {k:v for k,v in doc.nsmap.items() if k}
paragraphs = doc.xpath(selector,namespaces=nsDict)
for p in paragraphs:
    print(bool(p.xpath(".//ancestor::w:tbl",namespaces=nsDict)))
>>>>False
>>>>False
>>>>False
>>>>False
>>>>False
>>>>False
>>>>True
>>>>False
```

The expected behavior is that the paragraph xpath selector is mutually exclusive with the parent doc element-level xpath selector.  The paragraph boolean check should always be `False`.

How can I amend my initial selector so that no elements are picked up that have `w:tbl` as ancestors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial XPath is fine; it is your testing XPath that is faulty.

Your testing XPath,

```
.//ancestor::w:tbl
```

does *not* select `w:tbl` ancestors at the current node; it selects `w:tbl` ancestors of any of the descendents of the current node.

The case where a paragraph has no ancestors that are tables but does have a descendent table that contains a paragraph would yield `True` for your test, for example.

Change it instead to

```
ancestor::w:tbl
```

to select the `w:tbl` ancestors of the *current* node.